Decryption program only returns the first 40 characters
I was writing a simple encryption and decryption C program and encountered a bug where the program would not receive more than 40 character of input and would only return the first 40 character when decrypted.
I tried playing around with the buffer but did not seem to work. The problem might lies in the hex_to_str function. Please let me know where I did wrong. Any help would be appreciated.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Function prototypes for the various functions used within the program */
void printMenu(void);
int check_input(void);
void start_encrypt(void);
void start_decrypt(void);
void xor_encrypt_decrypt(const char *input, char *output, const char *key, int data_len);
char* caesar_encrypt(const char *message, int shift);
char* caesar_decrypt(const char *encrypted, int shift);
int is_alpha(char c);
void hex_to_str(char *str, char *hex);
void remove_spaces(const char *input, char *output);

int main() {
    int choice = 0;
    /* Main loop that continues until the user selects the exit option (5) */
    while(choice != 5){ 
        printMenu(); /* Display main menu */
        printf("Enter your choice>\n");
        choice = check_input(); /* Read and validate user input */
        if (choice == 1) {
            start_encrypt(); /* Encrypt a message if choice is 1 */
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            start_decrypt(); /* Decrypt a message if choice is 2 */
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Displays the main menu options for the program */
/* This is just a test menu The real menu would be, for example, send, inbox, etc */
void printMenu(void){
    printf("\nE-mail encrypt and decrypt System\n"
        "1. Encrypt a message\n"
        "2. Decrypt a message\n"
        "3. Search\n"
        "4. Send\n"
        "5. Exit the program\n");
}

/* Checks user input for menu selection, ensuring it's a valid integer within the menu range */
int check_input(void){
    int number;
    int result = scanf(" %d", &number); /* Read integer input */
    while (result != 1 || number < 1 || number > 5) { /* Validate input */
        while (getchar() != '\n'); /* Clear the input buffer */
        printf("Invalid choice.\n");
        printMenu(); /* Re-display menu */
        printf("Enter your choice>\n");
        result = scanf(" %d", &number);
    }
    return number; 
}

/* Handles the encryption of a message using Caesar and XOR encryption */
void start_encrypt() {
    char message[8192], key[1024];
    int shift, i;

    printf("Enter a message to encrypt: \n");
    /* Clear input buffer to prevent reading leftover newline characters */
    while(getchar() != '\n' && getchar() != EOF);  
    if (fgets(message, sizeof(message), stdin) == NULL) return; /* Read the message from user */
    message[strcspn(message, "\n")] = 0;  /* Remove newline character from input */

    printf("Enter shift amount (1-25): ");
    /* Validate shift amount and prompt until a valid number is entered */
    while(scanf("%d", &shift) != 1 || shift < 1 || shift > 25) {       
        while(getchar() != '\n');
        printf("Invalid input. Please enter a number between 1 and 25:\n");
    }
    while(getchar() != '\n');

    char* encrypted = caesar_encrypt(message, shift); /* Encrypt the message using Caesar cipher */
    printf("Caesar Encrypted message: %s\n", encrypted);

    printf("Enter the XOR key: ");
    if (fgets(key, sizeof(key), stdin) == NULL) {
        free(encrypted); /* Handle potential input errors */
        return;
    }
    key[strcspn(key, "\n")] = 0; /* Remove newline from key input */

    char *output = malloc(strlen(encrypted) + 1); /* Allocate memory for XOR output */
    xor_encrypt_decrypt(encrypted, output, key, strlen(encrypted)); /* Perform XOR encryption */
    printf("XOR Encrypted: ");
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(encrypted); i++) {
        printf("%02x ", (unsigned char)output[i]); /* Print each byte in hex format */
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(encrypted); /* Free allocated memory */
    free(output);
}

/* Handles the decryption of a message using XOR and Caesar decryption */
void start_decrypt() {
    char hex_input[4096]; /* Buffer for hex input */
    char decrypted_hex[4096]; /* Buffer for decrypted hex values */
    char key[1024]; /* Buffer for XOR key */
    char no_spaces_encrypted[4096]; /* Buffer to hold hex input without spaces */
    int shift;

    printf("Enter a message to decrypt (in hex): \n");
    /* Clear input buffer to prevent reading leftover characters */
    while(getchar() != '\n' && getchar() != EOF);
    fgets(hex_input, sizeof(hex_input), stdin);
    hex_input[strcspn(hex_input, "\n")] = 0; /* Remove newline */

    remove_spaces(hex_input, no_spaces_encrypted); /* Remove spaces from input for accurate processing */
    printf("no_spaces_encrypted hex length: %ld\n", strlen(no_spaces_encrypted)); 
    hex_to_str(decrypted_hex, no_spaces_encrypted); /* Convert hex string to character string */

    printf("Decrypted hex length: %ld\n", strlen(decrypted_hex)); /* Use for debuging */

    printf("Enter the XOR key: ");
    fgets(key, sizeof(key), stdin);
    key[strcspn(key, "\n")] = 0; /* Clean up the key input */

    char *XOR_decrypted = malloc(strlen(decrypted_hex) + 1); /* Allocate memory for the decrypted output */
    xor_encrypt_decrypt(decrypted_hex, XOR_decrypted, key, strlen(decrypted_hex)); /* Perform XOR decryption */
    printf("XOR Decrypted: %s\n", XOR_decrypted);

    printf("Enter shift amount (1-25): ");
    scanf("%d", &shift);
    while(getchar() != '\n');
    char *final_decrypted = caesar_decrypt(XOR_decrypted, shift); /* Perform final Caesar decryption */
    printf("Final Decrypted: %s\n", final_decrypted);

    free(XOR_decrypted); /* Free allocated memory */
    if (final_decrypted) free(final_decrypted);
}

/* Encrypts a message using the Caesar cipher technique */
char* caesar_encrypt(const char *message, int shift) {
    int len = strlen(message); /* Get the length of the input message */
    int i;
    char* encrypted = malloc(len + 1); /* Allocate memory for the encrypted message */
    if (!encrypted) return NULL; /* Return NULL if memory allocation fails */
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { /* Iterate over each character of the message */
        if (is_alpha(message[i])) { /* Check if the character is alphabetic */
            char base = (message[i] >= 'a' && message[i] <= 'z') ? 'a' : 'A'; /* Determine the base for case sensitivity */
            encrypted[i] = (message[i] - base + shift) % 26 + base; /* Apply Caesar cipher transformation */
        } else {
            encrypted[i] = message[i]; /* Non-alphabetic characters are copied as is */
        }
    }
    encrypted[len] = '\0'; /* Null-terminate the encrypted string */
    return encrypted; /* Return the encrypted message */
}

/* Decrypts a message that was encrypted using the Caesar cipher */
char* caesar_decrypt(const char *encrypted, int shift) {
    int len = strlen(encrypted); /* Get the length of the encrypted message */
    int i;
    char* decrypted = (char*)malloc(len + 1); /* Allocate memory for the decrypted message */
    if (decrypted == NULL) return NULL; /* Return NULL if memory allocation fails */
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { /* Iterate over each character of the encrypted message */
        if (encrypted[i] >= 'a' && encrypted[i] <= 'z') { /* Check for lowercase alphabetic characters */
            decrypted[i] = ((encrypted[i] - 'a' - shift + 26) % 26) + 'a'; /* Decrypt using Caesar cipher formula for lowercase */
        } else if (encrypted[i] >= 'A' && encrypted[i] <= 'Z') { /* Check for uppercase alphabetic characters */
            decrypted[i] = ((encrypted[i] - 'A' - shift + 26) % 26) + 'A'; /* Decrypt using Caesar cipher formula for uppercase */
        } else {
            decrypted[i] = encrypted[i]; /* Non-alphabetic characters are copied as is */
        }
    }
    decrypted[len] = '\0'; /* Null-terminate the decrypted string */
    return decrypted; /* Return the decrypted message */
}

/* Performs XOR encryption/decryption based on a key */
void xor_encrypt_decrypt(const char *input, char *output, const char *key, int data_len) {
    int key_len = strlen(key); /* Get the length of the key */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < data_len; i++) { /* Iterate over each byte of the input data */
        output[i] = input[i] ^ key[i % key_len]; /* Apply XOR operation using the key, cycling through the key characters */
    }
    output[data_len] = '\0'; /* Ensure null termination of the output */
}

/* Checks if a character is alphabetic */
int is_alpha(char c) {
    return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'); /* Return true if the character is alphabetic (either uppercase or lowercase) */
}

    /*Converts a hex string to a regular string */
 void hex_to_str(char *str, char *hex) { 
    int i;
    int length = strlen(hex);  /* Get the length of the hex string */
    for (i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {  /* Iterate over each pair of hex characters */
    sscanf(&hex[i], "%2hhx", &str[i / 2]);  /*Convert two hex characters to one byte and store it */
    } 
    str[length / 2] = '\0';  /*Null terminate the string after conversion */
} 
/* Removes spaces from the input string */
void remove_spaces(const char *input, char *output) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (input[i] != '\0') { /* Iterate over each character of the input string */
        if (input[i] != ' ') { /* Copy the character to output if it's not a space */
            output[j++] = input[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    output[j] = '\0'; /* Ensure null termination of the output string */
}


Begin by removing parts of your program until the error disappears, then add back the parts one line at a time until the bug comes back. That should help you isolate the problem, and help you create a [mre] that can be easily debugged, and that you can show us.

Also, if there are standard C functions that can be used, use them instead of writing your own. Like for example isalpha, which will work portably across different systems, unlike your ASCII-specific is_alpha function.

Going back to my first comment, for future programs don't write large pieces of code without any kind of testing, or long complicated functions that do multiple things. Start with an empty main function. Build with extra warnings enabled, and treated as errors. When it builds cleanly, test the code in all possible ways. Only when it works, continue to add one very small bit of code, perhaps even just one or two lines. Continue like that, and you'll find that it's much easier to debug and fix problems as they occur.

Any reason why you added tags for C89 and C99? Do you want to mix both? Or find differences between them? And can't you use some more recent version?

decrypted_hex after hex_to_str(decrypted_hex, no_spaces_encrypted) may contain NUL character. strlen(decrypted_hex) returns length only up to this character. Do something like: size_t hex_len = strlen(no_spaces_encrypted) / 2; and use hex_len instead of strlen(decrypted_hex). Also use %zu flag for printing result of strlen() instead of %ld. size_t may be not equal to long int.

This is wrong: while(getchar() != '\n' && getchar() != EOF); Each call to getchar() reads another character. When the loop ends, the next fgets() will start reading at the character after` the one that ended the loop. So you'll skip that character in the remaining code.

@Barmar Ironically, but this part of OP code "works" fine: first getchar() reads newline left after scanf() from check_input() and the loop breaks. fgets() returns string intact.

@Kiên Show your entire input and output. My bet is: a char from your "XOR key" coincides with the same char in "Caesar Encrypted message", so "XOR Encrypted" contains 00 in the middle.
